# SharePoint 2007 - 2010 DB Migration

Tags: migration

I'm about to perform a DB migration of an Intranet Publishing Site. Is it necessary to create the site collection before performing the DB restore?

Comment: FYI.. I'm removing the 2007/2010 tags from your Migration questions since you have that information elsewhere in the questions and these aren't necessarily version specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be clearer, you actually only need an Web Application to which you would attach the database. I would highly recomand before doing that go through checking/testing at least by using:

1. Test-SPContentDatabase which will tell you if you got all other
   dependencies installed, etc. (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263026.aspx)
2. Run pre-upgrade checker (see here http://technet.microsoft.com/library/cc262231(office.14).aspx)

Also you would need at least MOSS with SP2 to be able to run these commands. There is so much documentation written on the subject. Start here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262792

Comment: It seems preupgradecheck tool was updated with the Oct 2009 CU. So people would need to upgrade to at least that in their 2007 farm first: http://sharepointreporter.wordpress.com/2010/07/30/fix-pre-upgrade-check-errors/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, typically the I usually do it is, provision a web application and a site collesction then I detach the content database, copy the database accross and attach db to the site collection.

Use this to mount DB to the existing sitecollection after attaching to the new server:

Mount-SPContentDatabase "" -DatabaseServer "" -WebApplication siteUrl